# Get value from actionbar menu item textview from fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem

I created action bar menu which is customization like one menu item can have one image and `textview` the `textview` value can be change while open one activity to another activity its working fine this action bar code i written in one class. now i want to get that value from action bar menu item `textvew` in fragment. so can some one help me how to get value in fragment.

my action bar menu code is

```
MenuItem menuVal = menu.findItem(R.id.action_rewards);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuVal, R.layout.action_bar_rewardpoints_icon);
View menu_hotlist = (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuVal);
ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
```

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: No i want to get value from the textview i don't know how to get. i am not able to access ui_hot textview in another fragment

Comment: Did you set custom view for ActionBar?

Comment: only MenuItem is custom view

Comment: ok but i don't want to whole actionbar custom i want only custom menu item. i want to access ui_hot in fragment

Comment: Do you want to access ui_hot in fragment?

Comment: yes i want to access ui_hot in fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store ui_hot in private variable. In fragment you get it through activity like:

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
```

Finally, get ui_hot from activity.
Hope this help!